# Merge two directories and keep the newest files

Tags: unix

Is there a unix command to copy the contents of a directory into another, but preserving always the newest files?

I mean, having directory A and directory B, I need to copy the contents of B into A. If a filename on directory B already exists on A, keep the newest of them, according to its creation date.

Comment: I’m sure you can do this with rsync. Hang on...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use rsync to sync the contents of two directories. The option `-u/ --update` has the effect

> skip files that are newer on the receiver

So you could use `rsync -auvh dir1/ dir2/`

`-a` = archive mode. Enables a whole load of options such as recursion, preserve basic attributes (permissions, owner, type symbolic links ).

`-v` and `-h` are verbose and human readable options. Not vital, but useful to see what’s going on.

I suggest you run any rsync command first with the `-—dry-run` option so you can check for unexpected results.

Comment: rsync did the trick without altering the metadata of the files, although options v and h wasn't really necessary.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You could use plain `cp`, with this option:

```
-u, --update
       copy only when the SOURCE file is newer than the destination file
       or when the destination file is missing
```

If there's newer files scattered in each directory, you could run `cp` once from each directory, only copying the newer files over the older ones.

Comment: When using this, the properties of the files are modified. Now all the files that were copied from B to A have their date modified to the moment when they were copied.

Comment: add `-a, --archive` (same as -dR --preserve=all) if you want an "archive" copy. *[The main question didn't say anything about attributes, so I didn't mention it; it's the first entry in `man cp` and you should always see the man page before running commands you're unfamiliar with]*